# Adding group to local administrators

Tags: c#, active-directory, console-application, directoryservices

I am trying to add an existing group in Local Administrators. The group `"ABC\Some Active Group"`  exists. I can add that through Windows GUI but I need to add it through code. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
public static bool AddGroup(string machineName, string groupName)
{
    bool ifSuccessful = false;
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry localMachine = new DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" + machineName);
        DirectoryEntry admGroup = localMachine.Children.Find("administrators", "group");
        //admGroup.Children.Add(groupName, "Group"); 
        admGroup.Invoke("Add", groupName);
        admGroup.CommitChanges();

        ifSuccessful = true;

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ifSuccessful = false;
        //logging
        Console.WriteLine(machineName + " ----------" + ex.Message);
    }
    return ifSuccessful;
}
```

and I am calling it like:

```
AddGroup(Environment.MachineName, @"ABC\Some Active Group");
```

I get the exception, *(its an inner exception)*

> An invalid directory pathname was passed

I also tried adding it like:

```
admGroup.Children.Add(groupName, "Group");
```

But then I got the exception:

> The Active Directory object located at the path
>   WinNT://ABC/MachineName/Administrators is not a container

I have been able to successfully get all the users and groups with `admGroup`, I can't just add one. Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: quick question...have you considered a google search..? 
[DirectoryEntry Adding local User](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999499/adding-a-local-user-to-a-local-group-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @DJKRAZE, thanks for the comment. Yes I have looked at that, but it is related to adding a User, I am trying to add a group

Comment: try this link may have some helpful stuff as well http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18102/Howto-Almost-Everything-In-Active-Directory-via-C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call AddGroup like this

> AddGroup(Environment.MachineName, "WinNT://" + Environment.MachineName + "/Some Active Group");