# How to add a group to local administrators group using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, active-directory, exe, local, directoryentry

I'm trying to write a program that adds a group named `grp1` to the local administrators group using VB.NET. I have tried the ways mentioned in this post: [Adding group to local administrators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412448/adding-group-to-local-administrators), but it didn't work for me. Below is what I have so far:

```
Function AddToLocalAdmin(grp1 As String)
    Dim localComp As string = system.environment.MachineName
    Try
        Dim localMachine As New DirectoryEntry("WinNT://" & localComp & ",computer")
        Dim AdminGrp As DirectoryEntry = localMachine.Children.Find("Administrators", "group")

        AdminGrp.Invoke("Add", grp1)
        AdminGrp.CommitChanges()

        Return True
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return False
    End Try
End Function
```

I found many articles on Google talking about how to add an User to local administrators group, but what should I do to add a Group to it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your error description "it didn't work for me" isn't very helpful. Do you get any error messages? Did you debug through the code to check whether any errors occur that your try-catch might swallow?

Comment: @Capricorn It stops at the line "AdminGrp.Invoke("Add", grp1)" and gives errors. I tried to put grp1.path and grp1.path.tostring there but none of them worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm I found the solution myself. The code below worked perfectly fine.

```
    AdminGrp.Invoke("Add", New Object() {"WinNT://DOMAINNAME/" & grp1})
```